# How to consider more than one no data value in utility gdalwarp of GDAL

Tags: gdal, interpolation, gdalwarp

I have to do a bilinear interpolation on an image with two no data values, using the utility `gdalwarp` of GDAL (http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html), so these two values shouldn't be considered in interpolation. How can I do this? I evaluated the `gdalwarp` options "`-srcnodata`" and "`-dstnodata`", but they specify several no data values, with each value corresponding to one band. The case of my image is different, because I have only one band with multiple no data values.

Answer (score 3):

If disk space and processing time aren't a major concern, then you could use [`gdal_calc.py`](http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal_calc.py) to pre-process your data before `gdalwarp`.  Create an intermediate file that has only one no-data value by converting one of the two no-data values to be the same as the other.

Suppose, for example, that your no-data values are `0` and `17`.  Then you might do something like this:

```
gdal_calc.py -A input.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="A*(A!=17)"
```

Whenever the pixel value is `17`, the expression `A!=17` is `0`, so those values get set to `0`.  Otherwise it's `1`, so it'll leave the other values alone.

If `0` is not a no-data value in your dataset, you'll have to be a bit more clever with your `calc` expression.

Answer (score 3):

I have recently came across the same issue. For example, in one raster data, I have two nodata values:
1.7976931348623157e+308
3.4028234663852886e+38

I used gdalwarp to set them to a unified nodata value:
gdalwarp -srcnodata 3.4028234663852886e+38 -dstnodata 1.7976931348623157e+308 input.tif output.tif

Similarly, you can reset multiple nodata values (e.g. a, b, and c) to one unified nodata value (c) by running gdalwarp multiple times:

gdalwarp -srcnodata a -dstnodata c input.tif intermediate.tif
gdalwarp -srcnodata b -dstnodata c intermediate.tif output.tif

Cheers.